# How can I save request from client on server

Tags: api, methods, next.js, request, response

So basically I have a api route when I request the data from client and send the data from the client that sent the request to another client. Concretely I have student user that has bought a course and I want to notify the teacher when the course is bought. When student buys lesson he sends his user_name and other data which I want to save on server and then send the data from user that sent it to the teacher.

Here is code for the

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export default async function handler(
req: NextApiRequest,
res: NextApiResponse
) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

const { user_name, course_id, author_id, courseName } = req.body;

const author = await fetch(
`http://localhost:8000/api/user-id/${author_id}`
).then((res) => res.json());

console.log(author.user);

const message = `Hi ${author?.user?.name}, ${user_name} has purchased your course: 
 ${courseName}!`;

res.status(200).json({
message: {
  message: message,
  courseName: courseName,
  buyerName: user_name,
  authorName: author?.user?.name,
},
});
```

This is the api call from student

```
const handleSendMessage = async () => {
const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/puchase-message`, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    // disable preflight request
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    user_name: session?.user_name,
    course_id: session?.product_id,
    author_id: user_id,
    courseName: session?.productName,
  }),
});
};
```

This is api call for the teacher to get the message

```
  const fetchMessage = async () => {
const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/puchase-message`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    // disable preflight request
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
  },
});

const data = await res.json();

setMessage(data.message);
};
```

This is the output

[image: output]

Comment: Did you try logging `author_id` from `req.body`?

Comment: Yes i did and from the student req it work but somehow it returns undefined when the teacher make req